# Avoid gmail blocking for Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, gmail

I was trying to send my Visual Studio Project via Gmail.but i am getting error "Blocked for security reasons!".Is there any thing i can do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont send it through gmail and use google drive, or dropbox, or anything else, or change the file type or compress and encrypt it

Comment: Zip it up, then rename the file from .zip to .piz.

Comment: even better create a free VSTS account and check in your code.  Give the person you are trying to send the code to access to the repository

Comment: zipping and changing extension doesnt work anymore. Using drive now, pita.